# <optgroup> Not working in jQuery Dropdown

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, .net, jquery-ui

I have a asp:dropdownlist which i have changed to jQuery multiselect. I have to group the data inside the dropdown. I am grouping this in runtime.If it is a normal asp dropdown its working. When applying jquery Multiselect its dosen't.

Source:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Styles/jquery.multiselect.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Styles/jquery.multiselect.filter.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Styles/style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Styles/prettify.css" />
    <%--<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>--%>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.multiselect.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.multiselect.filter.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/prettify.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            //Create groups for dropdown list
            $("option[classification='LessThanFive']").wrapAll("<optgroup label='Less Than Five' />");
            $("option[classification='GreaterThanFive']").wrapAll("<optgroup label='Greater Than five' />");
        });

    </script>

 <asp:DropDownList ID="MobileData" runat="server" OnDataBound="ddl_DataBound">
            </asp:DropDownList>
```

//Code Behind:

```
protected void ddl_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (ListItem item in ((DropDownList)sender).Items)
        {

            if (System.Int32.Parse(item.Value) < 2)
                item.Attributes.Add("classification", "LessThanFive");
            else
                item.Attributes.Add("classification", "GreaterThanFive");

        }

    }

  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
          ListItemCollection list = new ListItemCollection();     
           list.Add(new ListItem("1", "1"));
           list.Add(new ListItem("2", "2"));
           list.Add(new ListItem("3", "3"));
           list.Add(new ListItem("4", "4"));
           list.Add(new ListItem("5", "5"));
           list.Add(new ListItem("6", "6"));
           list.Add(new ListItem("7", "7"));
           list.Add(new ListItem("8", "8"));
           list.Add(new ListItem("9", "9"));
           list.Add(new ListItem("10", "10"));

           MobileData.DataSource = list;
           MobileData.DataBind();
   }
```

Where i'm wrong?

Comment: can you set up a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net) for us to look into the problem.

Comment: @Ravi: Since it is jquery Multiselect Ui i cant.

Comment: so what ? you can set up it, add those resources to jsfiddle

Comment: @Ravi: http://jsfiddle.net/CQScc/. Look into this. But the css and Js are not applying. I have added the resources.

Answer (score 0):

Its working for me [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZW3Z3/)

make sure that the case is correct in the select though,

if you have LessThanFive in the JQuery and the HTML Renders as lessthanfive then the JQuery will not return a match.

**EDIT**
I have created a solution with the code you have given us and until i call `$('select').multiselect();` i cannot get any styles applied either, and the option groups show up.

BUT once i do apply this script i get the same dropdown as given in [this](http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/) example. only then can i reproduce the symptoms.

Upon further investigation i looked and saw that i was calling the code to add the `optGroup` AFTER the `$('select').multiselect();`  was called,

so i think your alteration of the drop down is happening after the control is initalised.

put the script to add the optGroups as early as you can in the page, then add the code to init the multiselect control after that.

Comment: Its working for me like this. but wen i'm usinng jquery multiselect its not.